# Creating MS Word Documents in iPhone using objective C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ios, html-parsing

I have created a Rich Text Editor in UIWebview. My requirement is to save this text in .doc word file. How to achieve this. I am getting html content by using

```
NSString *strWebText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

Now how can I proceed further to convert it in .doc format? Or is there any javascript function to convert text or save text to .doc file?

Comment: Not yet.. I am just looking for d same

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word can open a .doc file that is really .html and will open it as such.  There isnt anyway for you to easily convert your html to a binary .doc file without significant code or the intervention of a server.

if you create a html file from a word doc, you will see the html produced.  You will find certain headers at the top copy these in your html and word should open it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not have any built-in support for <strike>editing rich text or</strike> converting between formats.  You'll have to find a library or write it yourself.

Comment: Rich text editing is possible in IOS 5.0 webview. I have done with rich text editing.. just left with converting it to word format

Comment: Awesome—I didn't notice that change.  Nevertheless, iOS does not have any mechanism to convert HTML to Word.

Answer (score -1):

you can use :--

[strWebText writeToFile:@"Data.doc" atomically:YES encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding error:&error];

Comment: you cannot create doc file like this way

Comment: doc files can be created by some framework.. not able to get any of them working in iphone :(